# Unity Remote 4 is connected but Shows black screen

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, remote-debugging, unity-game-engine

When I press play in the editor the scene runs for both the Game view in the editor and my phone.

But my phone just shows a black screen. It functions well. Meaning I can interact with the scene from the phone. I can pan, zoom, click buttons but blindly.

The model is GT-S7582. I'm using the latest ADB version. Phone is connected via USB and "USB debugging" is enabled and "Allow mock locations" is enabled. Unity version is 5.4.0b18 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: Did you check the logcat? Also, I don't think that is a good idea launching the game for both platforms at the same time.

Comment: I don't know the logcat. Where can I find it? ...What do you mean by both platforms? I've selected the android platform. @Cabrra

Comment: you said "When I press play in the editor the scene runs for both the Game view in the editor and my phone." -> I understood that when you hit play you launch to both platforms simultaneously. Anyway, I guess that you are using a windows machine. You can go to the command line (cmd) and type "adb logcat" this launches the real time debug that prints all messages from your connected device. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. okay I'll do it! thanks! _btw I'm using a linux machine. I mentioned I'm on Ubuntu. Doesn't matter much anyways_

Comment: Do you try restart unity editor, and check the editor setting?